# giving : `date +\%Y\%m\%d -d yesterday` as parameter to call another script from one script

Tags: unix

I am using $(date -d ''yesterday'' +%Y%m%d) as a parameter to call another script from a script.
this should take yesterday's date as : 20190808 as a parameter to call another script.

below is the line in say script abc.sh

```
sh /volcker/covered_funds/dev/bin/pqr.sh $(date -d ''yesterday'' +%Y%m%d)
```

now what is happening is that it should take $(date -d ''yesterday'' +%Y%m%d) as one parameter but instead it is taking "$(date " as one parameter.

I want to write the script in such a way that this : 
$(date -d ''yesterday'' +%Y%m%d) whole should be treated as one parameter.

Comment: This looks like it should work. So read the section at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info about "Before asking about problematic code" and hopefully that will help. Also, figure out a what to turn on shell debug mode in your environment (why are you prefixing cmd with `sh`. Just be sure you have `#!/bin/bash` (or what ever shell you are using) as the first line of your script and "mark" the script as executable with `chmod +x myScript`. That `sh` may be the cause of your problem, but I don't have time to experiment. Good luck.

Comment: Also, you'll get more viewers for your Q if you include a tag for the shell you are using. (Hopefully `bash` or `ksh` or `zsh`). Good luck.